# How to toggle CSSproperty with JQuery without toggling Class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make a button that, when I click the **button**, set position to `left=0px;` of a element and when further clicked set position to `right=0px;` and continue toggling when clicking.

But it failed because it write ass inline CSS. without **toggleClaas** and adding CSS property How can I do this with JQuery?

**My Code:**

```
$(".something").click(function(){    
  $(".name").animate({left: "0px"},1000);

  //when again clicked do this event
  //$(".name").animate({right: "0px"},1000);
});
```

**Instead of**

```
$(".something").click(function(){    
  $(".name").toggleClass("active");
});

CSS:
.name{left: 0px;}
.active{right: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let isLeft = true;
$(".something").click(function(){    
    const move = isLeft ? { left: '0px' } : { right: '0px' };
    $(".name").css('left','unset').css('right', 'unset');
    $(".name").animate(move,1000);
    isLeft = !isLeft;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by initializing the button by `right:0px` then whenever you click the position will change as follows :

```js
$("#something").click(function(){    
  $(this).toggleClass("right");
  $(this).toggleClass("left");
});
```

```css
div.a {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

div.a button {
  position: absolute;
}

.left{left: 0px;}
.right{right: 0px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
<button type="button" id='something' class='right' onclick="console.log('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```